# Google Map Api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am face the problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on converting the address to latitude and longitude this the my code

The code is

```
function convertAddress( address, callback, item ) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 
        'address' : address 
    }, function(results, status) {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            callback( results[0].geometry.location );
        }

        cords = [ results[0].geometry.location.pb, results[0].geometry.location.qb ];

        $.post( jobifySettings.ajaxurl, { action : 'jobify_cache_cords', cords : cords, job : item.job } );
    });
}
```

Comment: You are using wrong values for coordinates. You have to use `results[0].geometry.location.lat()` and `results[0].geometry.location.lng()` and not internal structure properties which are changing from time to time. And variable `cords`: it is not clear where it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't use undocumented properties (location.pb, location.qb)
2. don't put code that depends on a successful result outside of the check for success

   ```
   function convertAddress( address, callback, item ) {
     geocoder.geocode( { 
       'address' : address 
     }, function(results, status) {
       if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
         callback( results[0].geometry.location );
         cords = [ results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng() ];
         $.post( jobifySettings.ajaxurl, { action : 'jobify_cache_cords', cords : cords, job : item.job } );
       } else alert("Geocode failed, status: "+status);
     });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have a business account, it could also give you this error which comes from this response of the server:

```
{
  "error_message" : "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.",
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Which means that either you load the api too many times a day/too concentrated or that you try to load many addresses.

This particular response will also cause this error.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

Here you can find some tips that might help.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits