# Geocoding LatLong with Google Maps API Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've have been trying to generate lat/long from an address provided by a URL variable and display on a Google map, but the map is blank (lat/long clearly undefined). The problem seems to lie in the getCoordinates function, but I can't figure out what it is.

My code:

```
<?php $address = $_GET["address"]; ?>

<script>
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

window.getCoordinates = function (address, callback) {
    var coordinates;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address}, function (results, status) {
        coords_obj = results[0].geometry.location;
        coordinates = [coords_obj.nb,coords_obj.ob];
        callback(coordinates);
    })
}
</script>

<script>

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
var map;

function initialize() {


    getCoordinates('<?php echo $address ?>', function(coords) {
      var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

})

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

***Found the problem:

I was using coords_obj.nb and coords_obj.ob when I should have been using coords_obj.A and coords_obj.F as output by my console.log:

```
[Object]
0: Object
address_components: Array[8]
formatted_address: "1045 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA 94103, USA"
geometry: Object
location: pf
A: 37.7800206
F: -122.40959459999999
__proto__: pf
location_type: "ROOFTOP"
viewport: ph
__proto__: Object
place_id: "ChIJeaMNfoSAhYARY4zPZwV_vgw"
types: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Do **not** use the undocumented properties of the API (coords_obj.A, coords_obj.F, coords_obj.ob or coords_obj.nb; they can and do change with every release of the API. Use the documented properties .lat() and .lng().  Please post your solution as an **answer**, not an edit to the question (and accept it when you can).

Comment: related question: [Google.Maps.Event settings - Va versus Xa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816294/google-maps-event-settings-va-versus-xa)

Comment: related question [Google Map Api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442876/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-null)

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114797/google-maps-api-v3-only-showing-a-blank-map-when-using-the-geocoder)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you geocodezip. To avoid breakage on future API updates, I replaced with:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

window.getCoordinates = function (address, callback) {
    var coordinates;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address}, function (results, status) {
        coords_obj_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        coords_obj_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        coordinates = [coords_obj_lat,coords_obj_lng];
        callback(coordinates);

    })
}
```